# How to declare constant array param in C?

Tags: c, arrays, parameters, constants

I can write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(const int argc, const char * const * const argv) {
    argv = NULL;
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And this doesn’t compile because `argv` is const (which is good).

However a document I read suggested `char * argv[argc + 1]` as a better way to declare argv. But how can I make it so this declaration style makes argv itself const?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(const int argc, const char * const const argv[argc + 1]) {
    argv = NULL;
    printf("Hello, world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This compiles but I’d really like it not to.

Comment: `how can I make it so this declaration style makes argv itself const?` You shouldn't do that. `argv` is not const.

Comment: @Matt `argv` is a pointer argument to `main`.  There's no reason why it can't be declared `const`, as long as `main` doesn't change it.  That's the whole point of OP's question.

Comment: `argv` as a pointer need not be `const` and the array is defined by the standard to not be `const` qualified either. See 5.1.2.2.1p2

Comment: @Olaf `main` is a function.  If it wants to restrict one of its arguments to be `const`, why shouldn't it be able to?  I know it doesn't *have* to declare it `const`, but it should be possible.  It actually exposes a flaw in array parameter notation in C, since the desired effect *can* be achieved using pointer notation, at the expense of ditching the array size info.

Comment: @TomKarzes: "at the expense of ditching the array size info" You cannot pass an array to a function anyway. There is no information lost. The problem is not the array, but the declaration as such. He should not change the signature from the required one. The caller expects a certain signature.

Comment: There is no difference between `char * argv[argc + 1]`  and `char * argv[]` and `char ** argv`. So why not stick to the last?

Comment: @TomKarzes: No it does not! `argv` **always** is a pointer in the function. Please see my answer and read the standard. That's exactly the reason for passing `argc`.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, yes, everyone knows that you can't pass an array by value in C, and that it's always passed as a pointer.  But you *can* declare an argument as an array *including* size information.  It's still passed as a pointer, but it includes additional information.  In the case of `main`, the size information may not be allowed, but for any other function it is.

Comment: @Olaf you are right, though, that it doesn't affect the `sizeof` value, at least at the top level.

Comment: @TomKarzes: It is not jut "by value". Try `sizeof(argv)` with the declaration you propose. You will always get the size of a pointer. What do you mean with "top-level"? This applies to all functions, not just `main`

Comment: @Olaf Yes, you are right about that.

Comment: @Olaf By "top-level", I mean as opposed to other array dimensions in more complex array declarations, such as `int a[m][n]` or `int (*b)[n]`.  The first is, in effect, adjusted to the second.  But in either case, `sizeof(*a)` and `sizeof(*b)` should be `n * sizeof(int)`.

Comment: @TomKarzes: The standard is very clear: An array decasy to a pointer to its first element. Of course this is not recursively, as that would result in an incompatible access to the array: `int **a` cannot be used to access a 2D array, althought you can use the same `a[r][c]` syntax. That's what I mean with "identical syntax does not imply identical semantics".

Comment: Why would you restrict the definition with a size of the outer dimension? You'll still need to check `argc` in case there are not enough arguments supplied. And trying to use a variable length array offers no protection at all against the code in `main` overrunning it. You were supplied with .... `argc+1` strings, the last being `NULL`.

Comment: @Olaf This was just an example of where array size information can affect `sizeof` for a function argument.  The "top level", if present, is adjusted to a pointer, but any other lower-level dimension information affects `sizeof` just as it would if it weren't a function argument (after the pointer adjustment of course).

Comment: @TomKarzes: Not sure what your problem is. I already explained it is not recursively and why this cannot be. After an array is converted to a pointer, it is not an array anymore, so the rule does not apply again. For any access, 6.3.2.1p3 applies, though, but not for the argument.

Comment: @Olaf I have no problem.  I was merely being complete in my statement in which I introduced the rather imprecise term "top-level" to distinguish the top-level dimension from subordinate dimensions.  You weren't sure what I was referring to, and the entire conversation since that point has been my attempt to explain to you what I meant by "top-level" vs. "non-top-level".  All of my responses since that point have been answers to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the C standard, [6.7.3p9](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.3p9):

> If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers, the element type is so- qualified, not the array type. ...

So, the `const` cannot be applied to the array name. Either you use the pointer syntax or live with the non-`const` pointer. Note that this has no impact for correct code on most architectures.

As `argv` is a pointer to the first element in both versions, see [6.7.6.3p7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p7), there is in fact no difference between `char **argv` and `char *argv[]` arguments. You cannot pass an array (as an array) to a function.